# setsockopt() returns 255 when it is called to disable loopback in udp multicast

Tags: c, sockets, udp, ip

i'm calling setsockopt function as shown below to turn off the loop back of the same data gram which I send from the server to the client.

```
char loop_back = 0;
    if((loop_back_flag = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_UDP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loop_back, sizeof(loop_back))) == -1)
    {
    // Print Error message 
    }
    else
    {
    // print success message with loop_back_flag value
    }
```

But what I observe is: when I print the loop_back_flag, it is printing as 255.

Now my understanding is it should either return -1 on error or 0 if success.
What is this 255? am I making any mistake in my setsockopt function call?

Comment: value -1 is 255 when you put it in a `uint8_t` (or a `char` in your case, a `char` is considered unsigned too)

Comment: if it is -1 only, why it is not printing the error message in the if part and instead entering the else part and printing the success message with this value.

Comment: 1. *man setsockopt()* clearly states that it returns an `int`, not a `char`. So the actual return value is -1. 2. When any system call returns -1, you must call `perror()` or show or log a message containing either `errno` or the result of `strerror()`. You haven't done any of that. Your question is therefore not answerable in its present form. When you have a proper error message or number, post it here. Edit it into your question.

Comment: How is `loop_back_flag` declared?

Comment: Even that was declared as char, please see my comments below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: just declare `loop_back` as `int`

```
int loop_back = 0;
```

if you look at the man guide, `setsockopt` return an `int`

Comment: The signed-ness of `char` is not defined by the standard, but left to the implementation. Also, `char` can have more than 8 bits and an implementation need not necessarily use 2s complement representation of signed values. There is **no** `uchar` type. You mean `unsigned char`. To use an `int` is correct, and the actual issue: Any `char` type is plain wrong here. You should elborate this, not concentrate on `char`. The actual problem is truncation, a proper compiler wil warn about if warnings are enabled - as strongly recommended.

Comment: Thank you, you guided me towards the right direction, i modified both loop_back  as well as loop_back_flag to the type int and then modified IPPROTO_UDP to IPPROTO_IP and then it started working.